# window.status not working

Tags: javascript

I have written a javascript for chaging the status of the browser in case of ajax call requests. This works in local but later when it is deployed into some other website, it is not reflected in it.

The script used is

```
window.status='Processing..';
```

Answer (score 4):

[window.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.status) modification may be disabled by default on most browsers due to security considerations - consider this:

```
<a href="http://imac001hacker.net" onmouseover='window.status="http://whitehouse.gov"' onmouseout='window.status=""'>Visit the White House home page!</a>
```

Comment: ok. Can u please tell how can i use href while making ajax calls. I am not able to make that out. And again i am using the same browser, and the code works in local before deployment in other website, so it the code website specific also??

Comment: @dynamoG: security rules may differ for localhost and external sites (and for local files, meaning the file:// scheme.) That could be the reason it works locally but not on the remote. That said, what exactly do you mean by "use href while making ajax calls"? What is your specific problem?

Comment: i am making a ajax call on a click of button, and due to certain conditions i m not allowed to refresh the page, but the user should be informed that the request is being processed. Is there any other way to do it apart from status bar?

Comment: Why not display a progress dialog or something? Even if you don't want to use the `<progress>` element, you can always come up with something of the kind. Or even a simple "Loading...": http://jsfiddle.net/YfyDw/